# Postgresql Replication EFM how to reject inserts when Standby nodes are not sync?

Tags: postgresql, failover, edb, postgresql.conf

I have a 3 nodes cluster for **PostgreSQL 14** made by **EDB Failover Manager**.

When I turn off the two standby nodes, the Primary node takes forever to do the insert commands.

I don't want it to do insert commands, I want it to act like a read-only node (reject inserts/updates..) when there is no Standby node sync.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. If all synchronous standby servers are down, the whole system is down.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
How come then the insert commit?
It shows me that the standby nodes are idle in the efm cluster status.

Comment: No idea. I was just guessing that EDB uses synchronous replication from your question. Seems I was wrong. Did you ask EDB?